# NameError on a var that's clearly defined

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, pipeline

I'm building a NLP model using a pipeline and I have defined the pipeline.transform(x_train) like so,

```
%%time 
train_vec = pipeline.transform(x_train)
test_vec = pipeline.transform(x_test)
print("Checking that the number of features in train and test correspond: %s - %s" % (train_vec.shape, test_vec.shape))
```

That runs no problem but when I call `train_vec` two cells later I get a NameError.

```
clf_sv  = LinearSVC(C=1, class_weight='balanced', multi_class='ovr', random_state=40, max_iter=10000)#Support Vector Machines
clf_sgd = SGDClassifier(max_iter=200) #Stochastic Gradient Classifier
```

Then I call it here:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

clfs = [clf_sv, clf_sgd]
cv =3
for clf in clfs:
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, train_vec, y_train, cv=cv, scoring ="accuracy")
    print(scores)
    print(("Mean score: {0:3f} (+/-{1:3f})").format(
    np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)))

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-f81405de72be> in <module>
      4 cv =3
      5 for clf in clfs:
----> 6     scores = cross_val_score(clf, train_vec, y_train, cv=cv, scoring ="accuracy")
      7     print(scores)
      8     print(("Mean score: {0:3f} (+/-{1:3f})").format(

NameError: name 'train_vec' is not defined
```

At this point I've been just gone around the problem by calling pipeline.transform(x_train) directly but it's still maddening. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This looks like you have these as separate snippets in a Jupyter notebook or similar. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct I'm using Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Just a sanity check: are these cells in the order they appear in the question, and has the first cell been executed?  Imports generally go at the top of the file (not necessary but custom), so it gives the impression that the cell with the error is at the top